# Getting error 429 on Cloudflare when using CURL

Tags: curl, cloudflare, http-status-code-429

I am trying to pull data from a server using CURL.
The website I am pulling from is obviously behind Cloudflare.
Even though I am sending the exact same request (including same http headers), I still
get error 429 returned from Cloudflare.

I know that normally 429 is returned when you hit some rate limit, like too many requests, specific user-agents etc. But in this case, it gets triggered even if it's the very first request from a completely new IP and computer and with the exact same RAW request.

The owner of the website must have put some special rate limit to 0 request for some unknown meta data, I just can't figure out what.

If the request from my browser and from curl looks exactly the same, what other things can Cloudflare trigger on? TLS versions?